# How to change my language layout hotkeys preferences in windows 7 and 10, using PowerShell?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-10, powershell, language

In windows 7 and 10 there is an option, that once modified, allows me, for example, to change language to English by pressing alt+shift+3, to Russian by alt+shift+2 and to Ukrainian by alt+shift+1. Every time I reinstall windows, or sitting on another computer I need to go to Control panel > language > bla bla bla etc. I want to simplify that process, so I save that script file, or command on my Cloud Drive, Just run it (assuming I have Administrator privileges), and be good to go. What is the best way to do it? 
(I don't necessarily need exact answer, maybe just tell me what to google, and I'll be thankful :))

Comment: Have you found the answer?

Answer (score 2):

Is it what you were looking for:

https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/How-to-change-the-system-5a963f8e